# How to set Nexus feed and src URL to https

Tags: nexus

I am new to this forum and my searches haven't found a solution to my problem.

I am having an issue with Sonatype Nexus v2.11.4-01. This is the OSS version. The repo server is behind a load balancer which is handling all the SSL and redirecting via http to the Nexus server.

I have a windows server using a chocolatey client, v0.9.9.11, configured to use the source: https://repo.agent.company.com/nexus/service/local/nuget/NuGet/

This windows server is on a network that does not allow port 80 traffic in or out. The commands choco list and choco search work correctly. However, when I try to run choco install agent -y, I get an error about not being able to get to the repo.

If I open the following in a browser: https://repo.agent.company.com/nexus/service/local/nuget/NuGet/Packages/
I see in the response:
xml:base="http://repo.agent.company.com/nexus/service/local/nuget/NuGet/"
and
src="http://repos.agent.company.com/nexus/service/local/nuget/NuGet/"

My question is, how do I get the xml:base and src URL's to have https? Wireshark has shown me that the initial communications are done via https, but the download is initiated via http, which seems to match what I am seeing in the Package URL response.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a reverse proxy of some sort running in front of Nexus?

If so, it has to be configured to set the X-Forwarded-Proto header:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Installation+and+Running#InstallationandRunning-Example:ReverseProxySSLTerminationatBasePath

Comment: Thank you I will look into this. We use an F5 Networks BigIP load balancer in front of the repo server. I do believe we can set the X-Forwarded-Proto header. I will post an update once I check this out.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. I indeed had to set the x-forwarder-proto on the load balancer. Thank you for the helpl